# Alamofire and memory warning in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am new at Alamofire framework. I try to download data file. The code is :

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, urlStr, { (temporaryURL, response) in
            if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                .URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
                    inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
                as? NSURL {
                    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

                    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
            }

            return temporaryURL
        })
```

File downloading successfully. However all process doing with memory. As you see the problem is, if i try to download big file(I mean over 50mb), i got didReceiveMemoryWarning and app closed itself. How i can prevent that?

In test I try to download a movie (size is 220mb) and in simulator, memory usage goes up to 500mb. and when i try my phone. it closed itself after showin memory warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download large files, you may consider another lib called [TCBlobDownloadSwift](https://github.com/thibaultCha/TCBlobDownloadSwift) by thibaultCha. It is a Swift version of TCBlobDownload, which was tested with files from ~150MB to ~1.2GB, mostly videos.

Its usage is similar to Alamofire:

```
import TCBlobDownloadSwift

// Here is a simple delegate implementing TCBlobDownloadDelegate.
class DownloadHandler: NSObject, TCBlobDownloadDelegate {
  init() {}

  func download(download: TCBlobDownload, didProgress progress: Float, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    println("\(progress*100)% downloaded")
  }

  func download(download: TCBlobDownload, didFinishWithError error: NSError?, atLocation location: NSURL?) {
    println("file downloaded at \(location)")
  }
}

let fileURL = NSURL(string: "http://some.huge/file.mp4")
let download = TCBlobDownloadManager.sharedInstance
                                    .downloadFileAtURL(fileURL!, toDirectory: nil, withName: nil, andDelegate: DownloadHandler())
```